# Python-Parse email Body and truncate MIME headers

Tags: python, email, parsing, mime

I have an email body which looks somewhat like .

Now I want to remove all the header from it and just have the conversation email text. How can I do it in python?

I tried email.parser module but that isn't giving me the result which I want.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
import email
a="""--c66f5985-233d-4e89-b598-6398b60cbe00
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
     differences="Content-Type";
    boundary="d5eff9f8-76b3-4320-adfb-1e51add8fa8f"

--d5eff9f8-76b3-4320-adfb-1e51add8fa8f
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

THis is a demo email body

Thanks And Regards,
Ana
"""



b = email.message_from_string(a)
if b.is_multipart():
    for payload in b.get_payload():
        # if payload.is_multipart(): ...
        print (payload.get_payload())
else:
    print (b.get_payload())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib,email

hst = "your.host.adresse.com"
usr = "login"
pwd = "password"

imap = imaplib.IMAP4(hst)

try:
    imap.login(usr, pwd)
except Exception as e:
    raise IOError(e)

try:
    imap.select("Inbox") # Tell Imap where to go
    result, data = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    latest = data[0].split()[-1]
    result, data = imap.uid('fetch', latest, '(RFC822)')
    a = data[0][1] # This contains the Mail Data


except Exception as e:
    raise IOError(e)

b = email.message_from_string(a)
if b.is_multipart():
    for payload in b.get_payload():
        b = (payload.get_payload())
else:
    b = (b.get_payload())

print b
```

This removes all the stuff from the mail you don't want in the final text. I've tested this with your code. You didn't show how you import the mail (your `a`) so i guess that's where you get the decoding problem from.

If you have any trouble with HTML Mails:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(b, 'html.parser')
soup = soup.get_text()
print soup
```

That should do the job for now, but I'd advise you to change the default python parser to lxml or html5lib.

Comment: And I am just facilitated with emailbody as shown above , with no hostnames and other credentials...