# Suppressing MimeText Header

Tags: windows, python-3.6, thunderbird, mime-message

Noob, trying to automate sending infrequent personalized emails to a few dozen people, using Python and Thunderbird (I'm fine if I have to click send on each one). Unfortunately, I end up with the following extra header in the body of each message, which I would like to suppress:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

My code is below:

```
def send_email(name, email_address):
    os.system("thunderbird -compose to= 'to',subject='subject',body='body'")
    tbirdPath = r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['To'] = email_address
    msg['Subject'] = 'Hello Friend'

    # Body of Email - part of code with display problem (in Thunderbird)
    body = "Dear {}".format(name) +  '\n' + '\n'  + "This is the body." + '\n'  + '\n'  + "The End." + '\n'
    composeCommand = 'format=html,to={},subject={},body={}'.format(msg['To'], msg['Subject'], MIMEText(body))
    subprocess.Popen([tbirdPath, '-compose', composeCommand])
```

When I print to the console, I get the body I expect, but get the extra lines/header when Thunderbird populates. From the first article below, it looks like get_payload can address this (but I have no idea how). Also, I moved to MIME after having no success otherwise, and suspect that is the source of my header. ([String Formatting in Python/Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502776/string-formatting-in-python-thunderbird)). Simple answers I can implement are preferred.

[Strange unwanted header when reading text file with MIMEText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305932/strange-unwanted-header-when-reading-text-file-with-mimetext)
[Python-Parse email Body and truncate MIME headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650352/python-parse-email-body-and-truncate-mime-headers)

Answer (score -1):

You can just truncate as many chars as necessary at the start of body to get rid of the header, i.e.

```
body = body[96:] 
composeCommand = "format=html,to={},subject={},body='{}'".format(msg['To'], msg['Subject'], body)
```